# How do I set my Java window (JFrame, actually) to the correct resolution?

Tags: java, jframe, window, size

I'm mucking about in Java by modifying [Jamal's pong game](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/27197/pong-game-in-java) and now I've noticed that the [entire window](http://i.imgur.com/RXtdMAM.png) is literally 800x600, but that's not what I want! **I want the *frame* to be 800x600** and *around that* to be the window 8's fancy borders. It makes little sense to me to ask Java for a 800x600 JFrame and then get a 794x571 frame to work with!

---

The main code to set the window:

```
public Main() {
    // cvars contains variables from JPong.ini (It's an extended class from the ini4j library)
    cvars = CVarList.getInstance();

    // get(sectionName, optionName, classtype, defaultValue)
    setSize(cvars.get("Window", "width", int.class, 800),
            cvars.get("Window", "height", int.class, 600));
    setTitle(cvars.get("Window", "title", String.class, "JPong"));
    setResizable(cvars.get("Window", "resizable", boolean.class, false));
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    table = new Table(this);
    add(table);
}
```

---

The reason I found out was because I changed the racket/paddle speed and the racket/paddles got stuck at either end of the window, so after modifying the code the paddles didn't stick anymore, but now they moved a little bit out of the visible frame (because I used 0 and the window's height in the logic to stop the racket/paddle)

Now I wonder how many Java windows are actually sized wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `JPanel` which contains the `Table`, within it, override it's `getPreferredSize` method and return the desired size you want

```
public class TableWrapperPanel extends JPanel {
    private Table table;
    public TableWrapperPanel(Table table) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.table = table;
        add(table);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        cvars = CVarList.getInstance();
        return new Dimension(cvars.get("Window", "width", int.class, 800),
            cvars.get("Window", "height", int.class, 600));
    }
}
```

Now, in your main method, create an instance of the `TableWrapperPanel` and add it to your "window", calling `pack` after you have done so, this will pack the window around your content.

```
public Main() {
    // cvars contains variables from JPong.ini (It's an extended class from the ini4j library)
    cvars = CVarList.getInstance();

    // get(sectionName, optionName, classtype, defaultValue)
    setSize(cvars.get("Window", "width", int.class, 800),
            cvars.get("Window", "height", int.class, 600));
    setTitle(cvars.get("Window", "title", String.class, "JPong"));
    setResizable(cvars.get("Window", "resizable", boolean.class, false));
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    TableWrapperPanel wrapper = new TableWrapper(table);
    add(wrapper );
    pack();
    setVisible(true);
}
```

Alternatively, you could just create a custom version of `Table` which overrides the `getPreferredSize` method itself

```
public class SizableTable extends Table { 
    //... Constructors ...

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        cvars = CVarList.getInstance();
        return new Dimension(cvars.get("Window", "width", int.class, 800),
            cvars.get("Window", "height", int.class, 600));
    }
}
```

And instead of creating an instance of `Table` in the `main` method, create an instance of `SizableTable`, adding it to the window and then calling pack

Answer (score 0):

Try `getContentPane().setPreferredSize(cvars.get("Window", "width", int.class, 800),cvars.get("Window", "height", int.class, 600));` and call `pack()` after showing the window.

Or you can set the preferred size of the table as well.

Comment: My JFrame is now 12 pixels too large (wat?) and nothing is being drawn in the window. Things *are* being drawn when I only remove pack(), but the window is then back at its old size.

Comment: Have you tried the other method? To set the table's size